# Как перенести вывод после точки на новую строку?

Tags: bash, grep

В Libux grep-ом получаю предложения из файла

```
grep -E '[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:lower:][:punct:] ]*\.' sentence.txt
```

Подскажите, как сделать вывод после точки на новую строку?

Comment: `grep -oE` возможно поможет

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: Можно содержимаое файла? Чтобы было чё тестить.